# How to add Internationalization in WordPress using Javascript/React?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I am trying to follow this article https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/internationalization/ in order to translate my block.

I created my block using https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/ script.

Then in my `gutenpride.php`, I added this code.

```
function myguten_set_script_translations()
{
    wp_register_script('myguten-script', plugins_url('/temp.js', __FILE__), ['wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element'], filemtime(__DIR__ . '/temp.js'));

    wp_set_script_translations('myguten-script', 'myguten', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'languages');

    wp_localize_script('myguten-script', 'myguten', [
        'plugin_url' => plugins_url('/', __FILE__),
    ]);

    wp_enqueue_script('myguten-script');
}
add_action('init', 'myguten_set_script_translations');
```

As you can see, I am registering a `temp.js` file and giving it all the required dependencies.

The `temp.js` file works and is running.

As instructed by the translation article I added two files in my `language` folder

```
1. myguten-co.po
2. myguten.pot
```

Then I created the JSON file for `myguten-co.po` and changed the site language to `Esperanto`.

But when I see the block or add the new block yet I do not get the translated label.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you do not use `register_block_type` in PHP, which is now recommended way to register block. I am assuming you register block in the front-end ( I am not familiar with create-block ), and instead that I inspect create-block, would you share your front end code where you also have translation functions? It could be for a various reasons that this does not function, one of more frequent being using incorrect text domain. Also, for better workflow I recommend using wp-cli and `wp i18n make-json`.

**Edit**

Use `wp i18n make-json` to create Jed-formatted JSON files. **This is the reason why your code did not work**. You only created .pot and .po files, but you have to supply .json files, since javascript loads them. See examples at bottom of [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_script_translations/).